# google font ubuntu special characters not displaying correctly

Tags: css, fonts, google-font-api

I want to display text in the ubuntu google font.
When I create a simple webpage with special characters it doesn't show properly. like this:

> touchÃ© â€“ â€˜Ã§Ã¡â€™

However, trying to demonstrate this in a fiddle I found the exact same code to produce a succesful display.

I've tried adding all subsets like this:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300&subset=latin-ext,latin,cyrillic-ext,greek-ext,greek,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

with this in css:

```
font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
font-size: 150%;
```

How do I get my local html file to display these characters correctly as well?
here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fek8fuaj/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your document, when read from the local hard-drive, lacks headers that tell the browser what encoding it's in, and it's guessing incorrectly. Add

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

to your document, that should help. Seeing two characters where you intend one to be is often a sign that you get a 8-bit encoding where you want UTF-8 (which encodes these in two octets.)